# XMLUNIT 2 using comparison with ignore element order with diffbuilder and namespaces fails

Tags: xmlunit

I am trying to use DiffBuilder to ignore XML elements order when comparing two .xml files but it fails. I have tried every possible combination and read many articles before posting this question.

For example:

```xml
<Data:Keys>
 <Data:Value Key="1" Name="Example1" />
 <Data:Value Key="2" Name="Example2" />
 <Data:Value Key="3" Name="Example3" />
</Data:Keys>

<Data:Keys>
 <Data:Value Key="2" Name="Example2" />
 <Data:Value Key="1" Name="Example1" />
 <Data:Value Key="3" Name="Example3" />
</Data:Keys>
```

I want these two treated as same XML. Notice that elements are empty, they have only attributes.
What I did so far:

```java
def diff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(xmlIN))
           .withTest(Input.fromString(xmlOUT))
           .ignoreComments()
           .ignoreWhitespace()
           .checkForSimilar()
           .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
           .whenElementIsNamed("Data:Keys").thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./Data:Value", 
            ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
           .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
           .build()))
```

But it fails every time. I don't know if the issue is the namespace, or that the elements are empty.

Any help will be appricated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you aim to match tags `Data:Value` by their attributes together, you should start with this:

```java
.withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
           .whenElementIsNamed("Data:Value")
```

and since that tag doesn't have any text, the `byNameAndText` won't work. You can only work on names and attributes. My advice is to do it like this:

```java
.thenUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAttributes("Key"))
```

or

```java
.thenUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes()) 
//equivalent
.thenUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAttributes("Key", "Name"))
```

As of issues with namespaces, `checkForSimilar()` should output `SIMILAR`, this means they are not `DIFFERENT`, so this is what you need. If you didn't use `checkForSimilar()` the differences in namespaces would be outputed as `DIFFERENT`.